# Automatically export numbered features to txt

Tags: qgis

How to automatically count the numbers of the buildings in a layer (CM_Buldings layer in the pic) and output the number as a txt file in QGIS?

[image: CM_Buldings layer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, Start editing the vector file and use Field Calculator to create a new field name it Count for example and use the following formula:

```
 @row_number
```

See the image below:

[image]

Then save the file as CSV by `right-click the vector Layer -> Export -> Save Features As`, and select the CSV file format and save the file after providing the name:

[image]

Then open the CSV file in Excel or text editor.